# How to resize a 2D vector of struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm working on making a minesweeper game using C++ but I'm having trouble re sizing a vector.

Here's what I have:
A vector of ints:

```
vector<vector<int> > mineField;
```

A vector of structs:

```
struct cell{
     int value;                //(-1 mine, 0 no surrounding, # > 0 number of surrounding mines)
     int state;            //( 0 hidden, 1 revealed, 2 marked) 
     bool isMine;
};

vector<vector<cell> > mineField;
```

The vector of cell is located in a separate .cpp file of a minesweeper class.
What I want to do is re size the vector of cell to have the same dimensions as the vector of ints.
and initialize the struct variable *value* to the values in the vector of ints and the struct
variable *state* to 0.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
this->mineField.resize(rowNum, vector<cell>(colNum));

    for(int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < colNum; j++){

            this->mineField[i][j].state = 0;

            this->mineField[i][j].value = mineField[i][j];
        }
    }
```

When attempt to run this I am only able to have the dimensions 5 rows x 5 columns (I cannot figure out why). Any
other dimensions exits the program and netbeans tells me the run has failed.

I have also tried:

```
this->mineField.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++){

        this->mineField.push_back(vector<cell>(colNum, 0));

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < colNum; j++){

            this->mineField[i][j].state = 0;

            this->mineField[i][j].value = mineField[i][j];
        } 
    }
```

When trying to resize this way, nothing works.

And this way:

```
this->mineField.resize(rowNum);

    for(int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++){

        this->mineField[i].resize(colNum);

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < colNum; j++){

            this->mineField[i][j].state = 0;

            this->mineField[i][j].value = mineField[i][j];
        } 
    }
```

Attempting this lets the program run but doesn't work for any dimensions combination.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why not just set the new on equal to the other one and then loop through the new one and change the state to 0?

Comment: It wont let me set them equal to each other because one is a vector of cell and the other one of int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you question, this should work.

```
vector<vector<cell > > mineField;
vector< vector<int> > mineFeildInt;

int size=mineFeildInt.size();//get the size of the vector for vector of integers
minefield.resize(size);//resize the vector for vector of cells

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
   int inner_size=mineFeildInt[i].size();//get the size of the vector of integers
   minefield[i].resize(inner_size);//resize the vector of cells
   for(int j=0;j<inner_size;j++)
   {
      minefield[i][j].state=0;
      minefield[i][j].value=mineFeildInt[i][j];//assign the integer value from the vector of integer to the value member of the structure
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version:

```
struct cell {
    int value;
    int state;
    int isMine;
};

int main()
{
    //declare source vector with sample data
    vector<vector<int>> mineFeildSource = { {10, 20, 30, 40}, {50, 60, 70}, {80, 90, 100, 110} };

    //Evaluate your destination vector
    vector<vector<cell>> mineField(mineFeildSource.size());
    for (vector<vector<int>>::size_type nSourRow = 0;
         nSourRow < mineFeildSource.size(); nSourRow++)
    {
        auto &sourRow = mineFeildSource[nSourRow];
        auto &destRow = mineField[nSourRow];

        for (vector<int>::size_type nSourCol = 0;
             nSourCol < sourRow.size(); nSourCol++)
        {
            destRow.push_back(cell{sourRow[nSourCol], 0, 0});
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```