# how to resize a vector which is a member of struct or class?

Tags: c++, class, vector, struct

I have written a struct and class, I wonder how can I resize them with the value that I read from a text file. Here is the struct and class:

```
typedef struct Chrom // creating the chrom structure
{
  vector<vector <short int> > bit;
  vector<vector <short int> > WaitingTime; //this is wij in the model
  vector<vector <short int> > WaitingJob;//this is wj in the model, sigma wij must be equal to wj for each job J.
  vector<vector <short int> > StartTime;

  short int FinishTime;// finish time of each job in each machine
  int fit;
} chrom;
```

In the program I read a number which is m. 
But in the program when I try to use `chrom.ShortTime.resize(m)`. It gives me an error. Even I tried to write a class like this:

```
class ProblemConstraint{ 
  short int Jobs, Machines;
public:
  vector <short int> Processing;
  vector <short int> t1;
  vector <short int> t2;
  short int M;
  short int W;
  void set_values(int, int);
  void resize(){
    ProblemConstraint.Processing.resize(Machines);
  }
}ProblemConstraint;
```

But I cannot resize the vectors within a class. Any recommendation on how I can resize a vector within a class or struct in the program?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "typedef struct Chrom" - you don't need that `typedef` in C++, that's a C-ism.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229215/how-to-resize-a-2d-vector-of-struct

Comment: `ProblemConstraint.Processing` <-- `ProblemConstraint` is a type name, not a class instance to use dot operator. Inside of class you can access members directly, that is no `ProblemConstraint.` needed, or you can access them explicitly using `this` pointer `this->Processing`

Comment: Concerning your problem: Read the basic tutorials. This is standard stuff. If you get a direct answer in here, this means only that you will fail at the next task. Read the basic tutorials. That said, I'd recommend you to put your code on CodeReview. There are several issues. Variable names starting with capital letters, public members, parameters not being declared const, just to name a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is at least partially how you're calling it.

```
void resize(){
    ProblemConstraint.Processing.resize(Machines);
}
```

Should be this:

```
void resize(){
    Processing.resize(Machines);
    // OR
    this->Processing.resize(Machines);
}
```

There is no object named "ProblemConstraint" anywhere, that's a type, so you can't use `.` on it.

Comment: "*There is no object named "Processing" anywhere*" - do you mean *"ProblemConstraint"*?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x  Yes.  Damned typos.  Editing

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Anderson has addressed issue with your `class` definition - let me address the struct definition issue:-

With `typedef` what you have basically done is defined a type `chrom` of `struct Chrom` type so your `chrom.StartTime` is an invalid access. You have to **instantiate** a variable of type `chrom` before you can access the individual members.. Try this:-

```
chrom A;
A.StartTime.resize(10);
```